# MySQL/POSTGRES how to force foreign key to be NULL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLite3 database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pads (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE notes (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
pad_id INTEGER REFERENCES pads(id),
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
text text NOT NULL,
created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

~

I have tried to migrate this sql schema to mysql and postgres, everything seems to be working fine except for one detail.
The table notes should accept pad_id as NULL, if there is no pad a note should be saved but when I try to save a note without a pad I get an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError
IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) insert or update 
on table "note" violates foreign key constraint "note_pad_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (pad_id)=(0) is not present in table "pad".
```

But I should be able to save it as NULL, it works fine on SQLite3.

What should I change to be able to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: "DETAIL:  Key (pad_id)=(0) is not present in table "pad"." -- You're not inserting or updating to `NULL`, you insert or update to `0`. There's a significant difference between `NULL` and `0`!

Comment: A `0` is not a `null`. The first one is a bona fide value, and the integrity constraint will require the referenced row to exist.

Comment: thanks a lot for all the comments, so basically to be able to create a note without a pad I need to have in pad_id the value 0 but the sequence starts at 1.
I am really confused in how to fix that, any suggestion what I would need to do to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither MySQL nor Postgres has a problem, with NULL as padod see examples

Therefore the error messahe comes from postgres, but it is because of the migration

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
> email VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
> password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pads (
> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
> name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
> user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE notes (
> id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
> pad_id INTEGER REFERENCES pads(id),
> user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
> name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
> `text` text NOT NULL,
> created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
> updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL,'test','pass')
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO notes VALUES (NULL,NULL,1,'test','text',NOW(),NOW())
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ebd3f65d367b8a16dafa8ca28c82e006)*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
> id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
> email VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
> password VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pads (
> id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
> name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
> user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE notes (
> id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
> pad_id INTEGER REFERENCES pads(id),
> user_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
> name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
> "text" text NOT NULL,
> created_at timestamp  NOT NULL,
> updated_at timestamp  NOT NULL
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO users VALUES(DEFAULT,'test','pass')
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO notes VALUES (DEFAULT,NULL,1,'test','text',NOW(),NOW())
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1e166da2626862194d783f509b0359e5)*